# Using pandas to sort data from a dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which includes a column for dates. The format for this column is `dd.mm.yyyy.`

I tried using the recommended methods for sorting the dates to restrict the range to 'December' and '2014.' However, none of the methods seem to be functioning properly. I am considering trying to rearrange it so that it is in the format of `yyyy.mm.dd.` I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Can someone help?

Code such as 
`(df['date']>'1-12-2014')&(df['date']<='31-12-2014')` don't seem to work.

Comment: Are the values of the column stored as datetimes? You can verify this through e.g. `df.info()`. If you add the code you used to generate the dataframe, the question will be more easily answerable.

Comment: I think I need to use datetime, I'm new to pandas and am not sure how to format it. df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f') I found this code from another post, but the format looks incorrect for my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your dates are strings that pandas isn't recognizing as dates. You want to convert them to datetime objects first. There are a couple ways to do this:

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda d: pd.strptime(d, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```

or

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%d.%m.%Y')
```

In both cases, the key is using a format string that matches your data. Then, you can filter how you want:

```
from datetime import date
df[(df['date'] >= date(2014, 12, 1))&(df['date'] <= date(2014, 12, 31))]
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to pandas and python, so having this quick lesson was extremely helpful.